# Communicating 2 way between class in C++

Tags: c++

The basic idea I am trying to implement is call method of class A from class B and the other way round.
Here is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
void AppCB (uint8_t num, TempB* inst ){
    printf("Application Level Callback Called!!!\n");
}

void main(int, char*[]) {
    printf("Starting Up!!!\n");
    TempB instB( 1, funcptr_arg1 (&AppCB) );
    instB.funcB();
}
```

**callback.cpp**

```
void TempA :: tempa_cb (void){
    printf("Calling Callback to B\n");
    tempBobj->funcB_cb();
}

void TempA :: funcA (){
    // some delay
    tempa_cb();
}

void TempA :: registerTempB (TempB *tempbobj){
    this->tempBobj = tempbobj;
}
TempB :: TempB ( uint8_t num , funcptr_arg1 AppCallback){
    printf("Constructor TempB\n");
    slot = num;
    funtptrB = AppCallback;
    instA.registerTempB(this);
}

void TempB :: funcB (){
    instA.funcA();
}

void TempB :: funcB_cb (){
    printf ("Call from TempA\n");
    this->funtptrB(event, this);  // <<<<<<<<<<<< this pointer is corrupted here. Hence it is not able to call the AppCB function in main.cpp file.
}
```

**callback.h**

```
typedef void (*funcptr_arg1)(int, void *);

class TempB;

class TempA {
    private:
        uint8_t tempa;
        TempB *tempBobj;

    public:
        void funcA();
        void tempa_cb(void);
        void registerTempB (TempB *tempbobj);
};
class TempB {
    private:
        uint8_t slot;
        funcptr_arg1 funtptrB;
        TempA instA;

    public:
        TempB (uint8_t num, funcptr_arg1 funtptrB);
        void funcB();

        // this function should be called from object of A.
        void funcB_cb();
};
```

From the code above, I would like to know:

1. Why is the "this" pointer (the one used to call the function) getting corrupted as marked in the code?
2. Is there a better was to achieve this?

Cheers,
Vineet.

Comment: You should never use C function pointers in a C++ program unless you have to communicate with legacy C code that requires this. These class instances should communicate via class pointers to each other.

Comment: Would you deep function pointer issues. It's the first time I hear about it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am new to C++. So exploring by best option :-)

Comment: Also, try to avoid using `printf` in a C++ program, and instead use `cout`.

Comment: @dreamlax You will find quite a few C++ programmers who are not `iostream` fans. Hehe.

Comment: Just looking quickly at your code, it's unclear why the `TempA` constructor is calling `tempBobj->funcB_cb()`, but it _is_ clear that is undefined behaviour because `tempBobj` is an uninitialised pointer.  This would happen when `TempB` is constructing, before any code inside that constructor is executred.

Comment: @pasztorpisti: I am one of them! Personally, I hate C++'s IO design. Having said that, the major benefit it provides is type-safety, which is something C's IO lacks. There's quite a few C questions on StackOverflow asking why their output is funny and it's because they used `%d` to print a `float`, or something along those lines.